# Mongodb: Check if an arrayfield contains a number or string

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pymongo

I have my collection say "myfollower" like following:-

```
{
   '_id':ObjectId('15423748234'),
   'userid':12,
   'follower_id':[1,2,3,4,5,6]
}
```

Now, I want to find all the documents that contains userid "4" as the follower. How can this be done?

Comment: `4 in myfollower['follower_id']`

Comment: just use db.find({follower_id : 4})

Comment: thanks that somewhat helped.

Answer (score 5):

The following could be used:

```
db.myfollower.find({"follower_id" : {"$in" : [4]}})
```

Comment: Hi BF,  In mongo the $in operator is like in clause in Oracle SQL.So One can uses the $in operator to look for values in array.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only looking for one specific "follower_id", the correct answer is:

```
db.myfollower.find({follower_id : 4})
```

The following query:

```
db.myfollower.find({"follower_id" : {"$in" : [4]}})
```

has another purpose.

The first query tests that any value of **follower_id** is 4. MongoDB automatically translate from a 1-to-1 match to a 1-to-N match if the field **follower_id** is an array.
The second query tests that any value of follower_id is any of the values of $in. In that last query you are doing a N-to-N match. The $in operator does a x-to-N query, where x=1 if you have one value in **follower_id**, or N if you have N value in **follower_id**.

Let's look at an example.
Here is the dataset:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52e7e35f4c735353309cf077"),
    "userid" : 12,
    "follower_id" : 4
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52e7e3784c735353309cf078"),
    "userid" : 12,
    "follower_id" : [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
}
```

And here are the queries and the matching results:

```
> db.followers.find({"follower_id":4})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52e7e35f4c735353309cf077"), "userid" : 12, "follower_id" : 4 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52e7e3784c735353309cf078"), "userid" : 12, "follower_id" : [  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6 ] }

> db.followers.find({"follower_id":5})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52e7e3784c735353309cf078"), "userid" : 12, "follower_id" : [  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6 ] }

> db.followers.find({"follower_id":{$in:[4]}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52e7e35f4c735353309cf077"), "userid" : 12, "follower_id" : 4 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52e7e3784c735353309cf078"), "userid" : 12, "follower_id" : [  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6 ] }

> db.followers.find({"follower_id":{$in:[4, 5]}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52e7e35f4c735353309cf077"), "userid" : 12, "follower_id" : 4 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52e7e3784c735353309cf078"), "userid" : 12, "follower_id" : [  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6 ] }

> db.followers.find({"follower_id":{$in:[5, 6]}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52e7e3784c735353309cf078"), "userid" : 12, "follower_id" : [  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6 ] }
```